# How to take two inputs on the same line

Tags: python

I want to be able to make a card and add it to a list of cards. The card has two variables, `cardName` and `cardNum`. I want to be able to assign both variables values in the same line using inputs from the user.

Code I used:

```
def Card():
  cardName, cardNum = input('Card name : '), input(' : Card number : ')
  card = f'{cardName} : {cardNum}/{cardsInSet} '
  library.append(card)
```

What I want:

```
Card name : Spark Jump : Card number : 123
```

What I get when running my code:

```
Card name : 123
 : Card number : 123
```

Comment: I could do that if the values are predetermined, but I'm looking to be able to take both inputs from the user on the same line without creating a new line from input().

Comment: It's not "a new line from input()", it's a new line when you hit enter to submit the first input.

Comment: How would I avoid hitting enter twice and also give two inputs, also I thought input() created a new line.